# OTEL Collector deployment on a Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

We are planning to implement OTEL with Kubernetes and I can't seem to find the correct answer when it comes to k8s.

The question is, do I need/should have the collector agent on each node or just have an Operator for the whole cluster.

What is the best method for OTEL and K8s?

Comment: Hello! This question is probably best asked in the CNCF slack in the #otel-operator channel rather than SO which usually takes down these types of questions. I'm happy to follow up in slack with more info.

Comment: The real answer is that all options are "best" in different scenarios. The [Deployment](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/collector/deployment/) section in the OTEL Collector docs covers all of them. For high-traffic services you may need sidecar collectors to collect, sample and forward traces. For a small cluster you may be able to use just one collector or two for resilience. For larger clusters you may need multiple and maybe a load balancer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could deploy a collector as a DaemonSet, which could allow you to not only collect metrics from pods, but also potentially the kubelet and other node-local processes, depending on what metrics you want to gather.

Otherwise, if you have other remote monitoring solutions, and they can read/accept metrics from a collector, then you can deploy a sidecar container into specific namespaces that you want to monitor.